# Reading a dropdownlist from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I've got a `gridview`, with one `field` as a `dropdownlist`.. 
I am trying to read the `values` inside the `dropdownlist` but the first item in the list is always `selected`..

This code is inside the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bank">
   <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" runat="server" OnLoad="dropdownLoad" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

at the backend, i am using the following code:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].FindControl("DropDown");
string s1 = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

What shall I do ?

Comment: Do you mean that even after changing the selection it shows the first item ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta yes... i choose a different item from the list, and when i click on a button to read the values entered, it will always show the first value of the list rather than the selected value...

Comment: Can you add code snippet on how you are assigning data

Comment: @V4Vendetta  first i retrieving a table using Oracle Data Reader... transforming that data into a datatable and binding that datatable with a gridview... OracleDataReader reader = BusinessLayer.BusinessLayerHandler.GetPendingRemittance();
            DataTable tempTable = new DataTable();
            tempTable.Load(reader);
            GridView1.DataSource = tempTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: So are they within a  `if(! IsPostBack)` clause ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta   yes they are.. :S and by the way.. i told you how i am populating the gridview... i am populating the dropdown list by the following code: DropDownList dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
            if (dropdown != null)
            {
                DataTable reader = GetList();
                dropdown.DataSource = reader;
                dropdown.DataTextField = "NAME";
                dropdown.DataValueField = "NAME";
                dropdown.DataBind();
            }

Comment: I would suggest you bind and event handler to dropdown's selectedIndexChanged event and check if even there you are getting first value as selected. In fact try to add client side handler also and see if the value is changing correctly or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code..

```
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
        DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drp");
        lbl.Text = drp.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not search in a particular cell. Instead i would suggest you to search the dropdown in the row it self.

So the code should be some thing like :

```
DropDownList ddl = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("DropDown") as DropDownList;
```

cheers.